# How to generate a content provider with GreenDao 3?

Tags: android, android-contentprovider, greendao

In GreenDao 2.x., there was a method called `Entity.addContentProvider()` which generated a ContentProvider for an entity.

How to do the same in GreenDao 3.x?

Answer (score 0):

With the same method Entity.addContentProvider() I am able to generate the content provider in GreenDao 3.