# How to generate Content Provider for Entity in GreenDao 3?

Tags: android, android-contentprovider, greendao, greendao-generator, greendao3

In connection to this issue: [How to generate a content provider with GreenDao3?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38935475/how-to-generate-a-content-provider-with-greendao-3/42858577?noredirect=1#comment72823199_42858577)

Can someone provide an example how to create a Content Provider for the annotated Entity in GreenDao3? 
For example my entity looks like this:

```
@Entity
public class Measurement {

@Id(autoincrement = false)
private Long id;

private Integer sensor_id;

@NotNull
private Long from_date;

@NotNull
private Long till_date;

@NotNull
private Double latitude;

@NotNull
private Double longitude;
}
```

I searched for code example from beginning to an end like this for a while, and it is really none of them out there.